# How to search for multiple Substrings in a string

Tags: bash, substring

I'm new to bash programming and I've been trying to write a function to search for multiple substrings in a string for log analysis.

For example:
I have a Log-File which contains a string like this:

"01-01-2020 STREETNEW Function Triggered Command 3 processed - New street created."

Now I want to search for 2 substrings in this string. 
The first substring I'm looking for is "Command 3" to identify which action was triggered. If "Command 3" is found, I want to search for a second substring "New street created" to check the output of the triggered action.

So far, I wrote a contain function which helps me to find a match and this works fine so far. The problem is, that this function is only able to find a match for one substring.

My function looks like this:

```
    declare -a arrayLog               # This Array contains my Log-File line per line
    declare -a arrayCodeNumber        # Containing the code numbers, e.g. "Command 3"
    declare -a arrayActionTriggered   # Containing the result of the triggered action, e.g. "New street created"

    #[... build arrays etc...]

    function contains() {
    local n=$#
    local value=${!n}
    for ((i=1;i < $#;i++)) {
    shopt -s nocasematch
    [[ "${!i}" =~ "${value^^}" ]] && echo "y;$i" || echo "n;$i"
    }
    }
#I'm calling the function like this in a for-loop:
contains "${arrayLog[@]}" "${arrayCodeNumber[i]}"


    #[... processing function results ...]
```

My function returns "y;$i" or "n;$i" to indicate if there was a match and in which line of the log file the match was found - i need this output for the processing of the matching results later in my code.

Unfortunately I don't know how to extend or improve my function to search for multiple substrings in a line.

What would I do to extend the function to accept 2 input arrays (for my matching parameter) and 1 log array and also extending the matching process?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Kind regards,
Tobi

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you restricted to use just bash or can you use some other command in the shell? `grep -n "Command 3" log.txt  | grep "New street created" | cut -d: -f1` will be very close to what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Consider this approach

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd=('Command 2'        'Command 3')
act=('Street destroyed' 'New street created')

for i in ${!cmd[@]}; {
    grep -no "${cmd[$i]}.*${act[$i]}" file
}
```

Usage

```
$ ./test
2:Command 2 processed - Street destroyed
1:Command 3 processed - New street created
```

From `grep` help

```
$ grep --help
  ...
  -o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
  -n, --line-number         print line number with output lines
  ...
```